# Why are some satellite solar arrays arranged in a zig-zag pattern

Tags: artificial-satellite, spacecraft, engineering, solar-panel

[image]

Some of the solar panel arrays I've seen on satellites are arranged in this weird zig-zag pattern.

Even when they're fully deployed they still have this arrangement. Why? What's the benefit from doing this?

Comment: That's artwork maybe from the cover of https://www.digitalmedia.hr/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/V-Ray-Next-for-3ds-Max-Key-Features.pdf. Have you seen this configuration on actual satellites?

Comment: Highly related, possible duplicate https://space.stackexchange.com/q/63210/6944

Comment: @uhoh I have, that was just the first picture I grabbed

Comment: When we "grab" images that don't belong to us personally, here in Stack Exchange the absolute minimum we must do is attribute the image to the source where you got it. Otherwise it's considered plagiarism and Stack Exchange takes that very seriously - your post can get deleted or worse. You should mention exactly which satellite this is, and credit the source of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensible solar panels are usually designed with a scissor mechanism. Due to geometry, scissor mechanism members cannot rotate a full 90* without pivot interference. As a result, panels can either fold flat or extend flat but not both. Compact volume when retracted is chosen over full extension. The small angulation between panels when extended has (almost) no effect on their functionality.

[image: https://www.justdial.com/jdmart/Mumbai/Scissor-Mechanism/pid-2022657235/020PXX20-XX20-200320234009-Y8U6]

Also, scissor mechanisms lose rigidity as they are extended. If it could be fully extended, rigidity would be close to zero, like a bicycle chain.

Comment: "Extensible solar panels are usually designed with a scissor mechanism" Citation Needed on that. I thought most modern deployable solar panels just have motorized "joints" that power the unfolding.